# iOS Mobileconfig for VPN - iOS will not accepting Proxy Settings

Tags: ios, vpn

I have created a Mobileconfig manually because I do not have a Mac with IPCU. With this Mobileconfig I want to configure a VPN. That worked wonderfully. Until I had the idea of using a proxy.

When I add these settings

```
            <dict>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Global HTTP Proxy</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Global HTTP Proxy</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.proxy.http.global.CF237754-A774-4832-A507-E944FB58A670</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.proxy.http.global</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>CF237754-A774-4832-A507-E944FB58A670</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ProxyCaptiveLoginAllowed</key>
            <false/>
            <key>ProxyServer</key>
            <string>xx.xx.xx.xx</string>
            <key>ProxyServerPort</key>
            <integer>3128</integer>
            <key>ProxyType</key>
            <string>Manual</string>
        </dict>
```

iOS complains that "this profile can only be installed on a supervised device". Any idea how I can get rid of this crap?

Comment: As the message says, you can only install a profile containing a global HTTP proxy on a supervised device.  The [configuration profile reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf) tells you which payloads are only supported on a supervised device.  A device can be supervised by connecting it to a Mac using a USB cable and running Apple Configurator 2 or by enrolling it in the Device Enrolment Program and managing it with an MDM.  If you can't do either of those things then you need to delete this payload from your profile

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suited to [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com)